# FactoryBean doesn't use when bean instantiates

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, factory

I am investigating how does `FactoryBean` works in spring framework.
As I understand it allow configure instantiation process.

I have the following beans:

```
@Component
public class MyInjectionClass {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    //get and set methods
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    @Autowired
    MyInjectionClass myInjectionClass; 

    public MyInjectionClass getMyInjectionClass() {
        return myInjectionClass;
    }
}
```

and following cutom `FactoryBean`:

```
@Component
public class MyInjectionClassFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<MyInjectionClass> {
    @Override
    public MyInjectionClass getObject() throws Exception {
        MyInjectionClass myInjectionClass = new MyInjectionClass();
        myInjectionClass.setName("name");
        myInjectionClass.setAge(12);
        return myInjectionClass;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return MyInjectionClass.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also I have wrote following code in my main method:

```
MyComponent bean = context.getBean(MyComponent.class);
System.out.println(bean.getMyInjectionClass().getAge());
```

It returns null.

What did I forget to do ?

### P.S.

I use `@ComponentScan("com.example.domain")`

All beans and `FactoryBean` located there.

### Solution

remove `@Component` above `MyInjectionClass`

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis fixed but I see old result

Comment: You've annotated `MyInjectionClass` with `@Component`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis yes. Is it wrong?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis it is really work - thanks